# How to enter text in a span using selenium

Tags: selenium

I have the following span element

```
<span style="-moz-user-select: none;" data-placeholder="Add a Title" class="title-editable supports-placeholder empty editable-region" contenteditable="false"></span>
```

How do I enter text into that span using selenium?

My code (which does not work in Firefox). I want it to work in Firefox.

```
this.browser.frame(1);
this.browser.click('.title-editable');
this.browser.pause(500);
this.browser.keys('text');
this.browser.pause(500)
```

---

In Firefox no text gets added to the span at all.

Comment: And could you share full HTML code with frame itself for this editor??

Comment: Actually you are using `.keys` on browser context instead of span, you should try as `this.browser.sendKeys('.title-editable', 'text')`

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/12aasqck7a/how-to-change-the-span-value